# In-app billing and Google Wallet OrderId

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I found the In-App Purchases orderId is always starting with: "12999763169054705758"

and I use it for protecting from Freedom. (I found: when I use Freedom then the orderId not starts with "12999763169054705758")

Um.. but I'm curious, this is just for me? or other developers equal?

So Question:

(for developers) If you have IAP, then your orderId always start with "12999763169054705758"?

Answer (score 1):

My in app products use the same start of an ID, and searching Google seems to find the same id start in other locations as well. I guess it's associated with Google Play. The best way to verify it was your app is to use an appropriate token. Also, the app name is passed back as a part of the string of in app purchases [(JSON PackageName),](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) use that for verification.